Django Form request.POST.get() returning None in terminal
So I'm trying to retrieve one element from a form but everytime I get None as value instead of a name for example.
Below the form html :
<form method="post" action="/contact">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
              </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Phone">Phone</label>
              <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="Phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="text">Text</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Description" placeholder="Enter your message">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>

      </div>

And my view.py :
def contact(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        print(request.POST.get('name')) 
    return render(request, 'contact.html')

Any tips or ideas on how to solve this ?
Thanks

The id="…" [mdn-doc] of the form element does not matter when you submit the form, but its name="…" [mdn-doc]:
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
